# How should a Model be turned to a Instance in ThinkPHP framework?

Tags: php, thinkphp

This question concerns merely ThinkPHP programmers.

So there are `Model` and `D()` in ThinkPHP. A model is very useful to communicate with the DB. But when we use `D()` to create a `Model` then find a piece of data. actually what we get is a array.

Then how can I get a instance that is of a class and has methods to use. To build methods in the model seems useless.

Should I have another class apart from the model， for example `UserModel.class` + `User.class`？

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I thought out.

```
class BasicModel extends Model
{

    protected $instance;

    public function loadInstance($id)
    {
        $this->instance = $this->find($id);
    }

    public function saveInstance()
    {
        if ($this->create($this->instance))
            return $this->add();
        return false;
    }
}
```